# update Collection record in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am currently working on mongodb for my current project.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a168f467cf3661df0df9c11"),
    "player_id" : "5a02db1170aaf41013d32747",
    "quiz_type" : "Single",
    "created_date" : ISODate("2017-11-23T09:05:10Z"),
    "questions_answered" : [
        {
            "question_id" : ObjectId("5a0ac1bfa9897441e038c2f7"),
            "player_selection_status" : "Pending",
            "time_taken" : 0,
            "points_gained" : 0,
            "like" : 0
        },
        {
            "question_id" : ObjectId("5a0ac212a9897441e038c2f8"),
            "player_selection_status" : "Pending",
            "time_taken" : 0,
            "points_gained" : 0,
            "like" : 0
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

above is my record in player collection, i want to update 2nd of

```
"questions_answered" : [  {
            "question_id" : ObjectId("5a0ac212a9897441e038c2f8"),
            "player_selection_status" : "Pending",
            "time_taken" : 0,
            "points_gained" : 0,
            "like" : 0
 }
```

like

```
"player_selection_status" : "Correct",
"time_taken" : 10,
"points_gained": 5,
"like": 10,
"answered_date":ISODate("2017-11-23T09:05:10Z")
```

i tried like below

```
updateData = {questions_answered: {time_taken: 10, like: 1, 
     answered_date: moment().format()}};
Player_quiz.update({_id: qid, player_id: uid, 
    "questions_answered.question_id": question_id}, 
    {$set: updateData}).exec();
```

but it is not worked for me.. please help me out with correct solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) for array update. Here we have `questions_answered` as array of documents.

The query to update the document is

```
db.collection.update(
    {"questions_answered.question_id" : ObjectId("5a0ac212a9897441e038c2f8")},
    {$set: { 
      "questions_answered.$.time_taken":10,
      "questions_answered.$.player_selection_status" : "Correct",
      "questions_answered.$.points_gained": 5, 
      "questions_answered.$.like": 10, 
      "questions_answered.$.answered_date":ISODate("2017-11-23T09:05:10Z")
    }}
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({
        questions_answered: {
            $elemMatch: {
                "question_id": ObjectId("5a0ac212a9897441e038c2f8")
            }
        }
    }, {
        $set: {
            "questions_answered.$.player_selection_status": "Correct",
            "questions_answered.$.time_taken": 10,
            "questions_answered.$.points_gained": 5,
            "questions_answered.$.like": 10,
            "questions_answered.$.answered_date": ISODate("2017-11-23T09:05:10Z")
        }

    }

)
```

In above mentioned query **$elemMatch** operator is used to match an element in an array